# Getting "input string was not in a correct format" when using Google's Finance Converter

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm using **Google's Finance Converter** for converting currency, but I'm getting the error:

> input string was not in a correct format

Here's my code:

```vb
Protected Sub btnGoogleApi_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim amount As Decimal = 0
    Dim fromCurrency As String
    Dim toCurrency As String
    amount = Decimal.Parse(txtAmount.Text.Trim(), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    fromCurrency = ddlFrom.SelectedItem.Value
    toCurrency = ddlTo.SelectedItem.Value
    If amount <> 0 Then
        Dim web As New WebClient()
        Dim url As String = String.Format("http://www.google.com/finance/converter?a={0}&from={1}&to={2}", amount, fromCurrency.ToUpper(), toCurrency.ToUpper())
        Dim response As String = web.DownloadString(url)
        Dim regex As New Regex("rhs: \""(\d*.\d*)")
        Dim rate As Decimal = System.Convert.ToDecimal(regex.Match(response).Groups(1).Value)
        lblMessage.Text = ("Real-Time Rate: 1 " + ddlFrom.SelectedItem.Value & " = " & rate & " ") + ddlTo.SelectedItem.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you debugged? What line does it break on?

Comment: unrelated note, you shouldn't be using decimals for currency values.....at least if this is dealing with either very large amounts or very small amounts.

Comment: running through it in debugger, what's the value of response right before it hits against the regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that error on this line

```
Dim rate As Decimal = System.Convert.ToDecimal(regex.Match(response).Groups(1).Value)
```

because your regular expression does not match anything and you cannot convert an empty string to a decimal.

The Google Finance Converter you are using does not return the same response as the old iGoogle api. Instead it returns an HTML page string. I suggest you use **another api** that will be easier to read the output.

If not, just change you're regular expression to:

```
Dim regex As New Regex("<span class=bld>(\d*.\d*)")
```

The converted rate is in an HTML span tag with the class bld. My regular expression is not great but that should do.

If the output changes, you will need to adjust accordingly.